# While executing simple stored procedure getting warning compiled but compilation error how to see

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

While executing a simple stored procedure getting a warning compiled but compilation error how to see.

Below is the query:

```
create procedure spgetdat
as 
begin
select empis empname, empadd from tb1employees;
end;
```

While executing above query getting an error. Pls suggest what needs to be corrected.

Regards 
Jitendra

Comment: please show your effort as [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9810829#) of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your Select statement inside the procedure is not correct. There should be into clause in the select statement inside the PL/SQL block.
It can be like below. You have to put a where condition for selection of one record or for best practice you can use cursor to fetch more then one record also.

```
create procedure spgetdat
as 
v_empis tab1employees.empis%type;
v_empadd tab1employees.empadd%type;
begin
select empis empname ,empadd into v_empis,v_empadd from tb1employees where empis = 'given name' ;
end;
show errors;
```

Comment: You need to use collection if your select statement produces more than 1 records.